# Why does Delimited Text Plugin display red sample columns?

Tags: qgis

When importing a CSV file (with associated CSVT) using the Add Delimited Text Layer feature, sometimes the preview window displays a column of sample text in a red font.

Does anyone know the reason for this? I thought it might be a data type mismatch with the CSVT file but everything seems fine with it.

Answer (score 1):

The Add Delimited Text layer module is telling you politely in non-verbal communication that you should not have those columns when you import them or else there is going to be problem later on with the output.

Comment: I figured it was something like that, do you know what would trigger it? Is it due to the presence of special characters (unescaped commas for instance) within the field, or maybe where truncation is occurring?